# Insert Word text box in any position - Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Good, someone could insert a text box in the lowest position of a word document in a floating way, attached an image, thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported using the high level `XWPF` classes of `apache poi` until now. But `*.docx` is simply a `ZIP` archive containing `XML` files in an directory structure. So we can create what we want using `Word` and then have a look at `/word/document.xml` in the resulting `*.docx` `ZIP` archive. Then we can try reproducing that `XML` using the low level `ooxml-schema` classes.

The following example needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` as mentioned in [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025). It is tested using `apache poi 4.1.1`.

The example is positioning the text box bottom right of the page. But not all printers will be able printing seamless. So the better choose would be using `mso-position-*-relative:margin` instead `mso-position-*-relative:page`. There the page margin determines the bottom right position.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTxbxContent;

import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup;
import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTRect;
import com.microsoft.schemas.office.word.STWrapType;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class CreateWordTextBox {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String textBoxWidth = "200pt";
  String textBoxHeight = "200pt";

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body text: ");

  CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();

  CTRect ctRect = ctGroup.addNewRect();
  ctRect.addNewWrap().setType(STWrapType.SQUARE);
  ctRect.setStyle("position:absolute"
   + ";width:" + textBoxWidth 
   + ";height:" + textBoxHeight
   + ";mso-position-horizontal:right"
   + ";mso-position-horizontal-relative:page"
   //+ ";mso-position-horizontal-relative:margin"
   + ";mso-position-vertical:bottom"
   + ";mso-position-vertical-relative:page"
   //+ ";mso-position-vertical-relative:margin"
  );

  CTTxbxContent ctTxbxContent = ctRect.addNewTextbox().addNewTxbxContent();
  ctTxbxContent.addNewP().addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");

  Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordTextBox.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();

 }
}
```